# GetFile Source Directory Does not exist in Apache NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi, getfiles

Created an Input folder and added an excel sheet. Then added the path on Getfile.
But getting the error "`INPUT DIRECTORY IS INVALID ,BECAUSE DIRECTORY DOESNOT EXIST`"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2QZi.png)

I am trying solve this to change the folder path and create the folder via command prompt. Anyone can please help me...

Comment: As you did not provide to many info regarding your flow, I assume that you are using a Windows machine and not a linux instance. If that is the case, you can try and change the / into an \.

Comment: try relative path -> only `input`

Comment: Already trying these two ways. but getting the same error.I there another way to solve this?